# Closed form of some interesting indefinite integrals

Tags: indefinite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form

While studying analytic number theory, the following indefinite integrals fascinated me the most:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{(x^2 + 1)^{z + 1}}\log x\,dx + \dfrac{\pi}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{(x^2 + 1)^{z + 1}}\,dx \tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(nx)}{(x^2 + 1)^{z + 1}}\log x\,dx +\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{(x^2 + 1)^{z + 1}}\log^2 x\,dx  \tag{2}\label{2}$$

where $z \in \mathbb{N}$. I'm looking for a nice closed form of $\eqref{1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ (however I'm not totally sure if there even exists one, but according to my intuition and references there should exist one).

Is it possible to find a closed form (obviously which is not in terms of integrals)?

I have tried integrating, using contour integration and residue theorem but it didn't get me to any nice closed form. I'm looking for a neat detailed answer with proper references for the tools used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do these integrals come from inside anlytic number theory ? Could you give references ?

Comment: @JeanMarie umm lecture notes of my brothers (when he took an advanced course on analytic number theory couple of years ago).